# How to make sure doLast even task is skipped

Tags: java, gradle, groovy

I have following code:

```
jar.doLast {
    def isFailed = jar.state.failure
    def proc
    if (isFailed) {
        proc = ['notify-send', "-u", "critical", "Build ${project.name} failed"].execute()
    } else {
        proc = ['notify-send', "Build ${project.name} finish"].execute()
    }
    proc.waitForProcessOutput(System.out, System.err);
}
```

when i first run `gradle --daemon jar`, it send notification, when i run it again, the jar.doLast doesn't run, i think it's because, gradle auto skipped jar since src is same with old src, so how to make sure jar.doLast run in 2nd case?

Comment: jar { outputs.upToDateWhen {false} }

Comment: But if `jar` task was not run, why do you want to send any notifications?

Answer (score 0):

thanks @Aarjav, i use following code:

```
jar {
    outputs.upToDateWhen { false }
}

jar.doLast {
    def isFailed = jar.state.failure
    def proc
    if (isFailed) {
        proc = ['notify-send', "-u", "critical", "Build ${project.name} failed"].execute()
    } else {
        proc = ['notify-send', "Build ${project.name} finish"].execute()
    }
    proc.waitForProcessOutput(System.out, System.err);
}
```

it will force run jar, and jar task doesn't waste too much (compare with compileJava), it doesn't effect build time